# how to have images as the background of a button while still having a drawable file applied to it

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm trying to have 4 buttons and each of them has a drawable file applied to them which changes their shape and color, but i also need to have an image inside each button. I tried to use the "android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_lodging_white"" method but the problem with this is that the image doesn't stay in the center of the button.
Here's my xml file with all 4 buttons:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/appBarMain"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?android:attr/actionBarSize" />

    <androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="?android:attr/actionBarSize" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView6"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
                android:text="TextView"
                android:textAlignment="textStart"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:paddingLeft="20dp"
                android:paddingRight="20dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/confirmed_boxes"
                    android:drawableStart="@drawable/icon_lodging_white" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button2"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_confirm_boxes" />

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button3"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_confirm_boxes"/>

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/button4"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:background="@drawable/white_confirm_boxes" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@+id/option_tab"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="20dp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/nav_view"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true" />
    </androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Could you show a scribble of what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put 2 drawables in a Button:

[image: Example]

- background: use as the button's background, the golden shape
- src: a centered image above the background, the profil shape

Comment: ty, i just had to change from "Button" to "ImageButton", after that i used "android:src" to set the image and "android:background" to set the shape and color of the button